# Como mudar o mês de um objeto datetime no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

boa tarde, possuo uma coluna do dataset pandas referente ao mês de setembro cujo .head() é:

```
[in] :df_setembro.head()

[out]:

 0    01/08/2018
 1    02/08/2018
 2    03/08/2018
 3    04/08/2018
 4    05/08/2018
```

gostaria de alterar o número do mês para o numero correto 09 mas sempre que tento fazer alterações o python aponta que a coluna é do tipo Series por mais que eu já tenha trocado para utilizado a função to_datetime, alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Comment: Uma curiosidade: se é referente ao mês de setembro, de onde surgiu o valor 8 no mês?

Comment: dados do governo federal, imagino que algum servidor deu ctr+c e ctr+v no CSV de agosto e não arrumou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível usar o método apply de um lambda que filtra as datas que tem o mês de agosto e depois fazer o replace.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
                   'month': [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12],
                   'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 31]
})

df2 = pd.to_datetime(df)

print(df2)

df3 = df2[df2.apply(lambda dt: dt.month == 8)].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month=9))

print(df3)
```

Comment: olha eu tentei utilizar esta seleção e a saída foi a mesma: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'month'", 'occurred at index codigo_infracao')

Comment: editado com o exemplo completo

Comment: olha, eu realmente estou perdido. minha data não está dividida como a sua em que cada coluna é referente ao dia, mês e  ano. elas estão todas juntas e quando tento seguir a sua resolução o resultado é: day is out of range for month